# Material navbar isn't opening in responsive mode on handsets

Tags: angular-material

I've created a site using the Angular Material schematic for a navbar which opens a sidebar when in responsive mode. I noticed that when running on the local dev server and using Chrome to emulate a handset it showed the sidenav as expected. Now that I've deployed to UAT and can browse from my phone, the sidenav doesn't show as I expect it to.

Oddly when using Chrome to emulate a phone, when switching it changes but when I reload the page I'm stuck with the sidenav not showing.

Here is my navbar.component.html

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
        routerLink="{{link.link}}" (click)="drawer.toggle()">{{link.label}}</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span class="md-title">South Island Practice Management</span>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let link of navLinks">
            <a routerLink="{{link.link}}" class="navlink">{{link.label}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

And here is the navbar.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, share } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent {

  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches),
      share()
    );

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}

  navLinks = [
    {
      label: 'Home',
      link: '/home'
    },
    {
      label: 'About Us',
      link: '/aboutus'
    },
    {
      label: 'Our Services',
      link: '/services'
    },
    {
      label: 'Contact Us',
      link: '/contactus'
    },
  ]
}
```

The site is currently live at https://sipm-b2ce5.firebaseapp.com

I'm at a bit of a loss having come over from Bootstrap where this sort of behaviour "Just Works™"